# ASP.NET MVC 4 Routing Query - Passing query-string to Index Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller with an index action.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
{

    return view();
}
```

I wish to pass id into the index action, however it doesnt appear to work in the same way as the details action.

e.g. if I want to pass id 4 into the index action, I have to visit url:

```
http://localhost:8765/ControllerName/?id=4
```

With the details Action... I can do this.

```
http://localhost:8765/ControllerName/Details/4
```

What I want to do with Index is something like...

```
http://localhost:8765/ControllerName/4
```

When I visit this url, I get an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /fix/1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Is this possible? How can I get MVC to automatically treat the index action in the same way as the details one?

Thanks

UPDATE - MY CURRENT ROUTES CONFIG

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

UPDATE NEW RouteConfig Class still doesn't work when I visit localhost:1234/Fix/3

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FixIndexWithParam",
            url: "Fix/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Fix", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Comment: we need to see whats in your `RoutesConfig.cs` file

Comment: Question updated with my RouteConfig

Comment: FYI: I edited your question to remove the references to EntityFramework, this problem has nothing to do with EF, it's all about the .NET routing implementation and the way it maps those requests to MVC controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** It's worth pointing out, /ControllerName/Index/4 should work with the default route.

With the default route there, it expects the second parameter to be the controller name.

So with the Default Route /ControllerName/4 is being interpereted as `ControllerNameController` Action `4`, which of course does not exist.

If you add

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "IndexWithParam",
url: "{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

before the default one it would allow

/Home/4 to be routed to `HomeController` action `Index` with `id=4`

I have't tested this, it may conflict with the default.  You may need to specify the controller explicitly in the route, ie:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "HomeIndexWithParam",
url: "Home/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

(Obviously, replace `Home` with whatever controller you're actually wanting to route to)

Comment: thanks, I created a new route, but still problems... see updated question.

Comment: sorry, I responded before i pasted it in. Please check update

Comment: You need to add the new route before the default route, they're executed in order

Comment: You can also add a route constraint, so that it will only match if the parameter is an integer.

Comment: How do I attach a route constraint?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs